# Am I using "as well as" right?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, coordinating-conjunctions

I would like to ask whether my usage here is right or wrong:

> Inman had started a long journey. He met persons who helped him, as
>   well as persons who tried to turn him in to the Black Guard whose job
>   was capturing and killing the deserters.

I want to say that somone met two types of people, and I thought about using *as well as* for that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that works just fine. The "was starting" and "has met" are concerning though; either they were starting, or they did start already. the easiest fix if you wish to keep the past/future tenses as is would be "He has **already** met persons who helped him as well as persons who..."

Comment: Or the past perfect "he had met," to indicate time previous to a past event.  Meeting persons happened before the starting of the journey.  Inthis case, "helped" and "tried" have to be in the past perfect as well.

Comment: I fixed that. Take a look at the edit , what do you think ?

Comment: looks good @user3730848

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** the original question has been edited to apply this answer.

No, this usage is ambiguous: it's not clear whether *as well as* means *in addition to* or *in as good a manner as*.

> John plays football as well as Peter.

Which does that mean?

If you mean *in addition to,* you can disambiguate with a comma:

> John plays football, as well as Peter.
>
> He has met persons who helped him, as well as persons who tried to turn him in ...

Note that your sentence has several other errors, primarily relating to mismatched and misused tenses. Here's a rewrite, taking your first verb tense as the one that is correct:

> Inman was starting a very long journey. He had met people who had helped him, as well as people who had tried to turn him in to the Black Guard, whose job was to capture and kill the deserters.

Comment: Thank you . I fixed that , can you take a look again please ? I want to say that during traveling he met that people.

Comment: You moved the tense of the story into the pluperfect, but the second sentence doesn't match.  Either make the second also pluperfect (with *had*), or begin it with a modifier that signals that the second sentence is in a different time than the first, e.g. *Along the way, ...*. Also, you are missing a comma after *Black Guard*. But this is no longer word usage :-)

Comment: should I omit the "had" ? @channel-islander

Comment: Either *was starting* and *had met* ... or ... *had started* and *had met* ... or ... *started* and *would meet*. Or others :-)

Comment: Also, please don't edit your original question ... none of the answers make sense if you do.

Comment: The putative ambiguity does not exist in the OP's sentence.

Comment: @TimRomano Read the comments. Or even the first sentence in my answer. The OP changed the question to implement my suggestions.

Comment: @Channel Islander: The ambiguity did not exist in the original version of the question either.

Comment: @TimRomano Nonsense. I see that you are one of those people who come here to win arguments. I just stop by from time to time to help people learn. Good bye.